# MVC Form Validation Thrown to All Forms in Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

so i have this view with multiple same form like this

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Special Leave on Purposes Rules</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Rule", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", placeholder = ViewBag.maternity }))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Set Max For</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(
                    model => model.ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.special,
                    "--Select One--",
                     new
                     { //anonymous type
                         @class = "form-control input-sm",
                         id= "inputEmail3"
                     })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ID, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Set Max</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Max, new { @Class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Max, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>

                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Maternity Leave Rules</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Rule", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Maximum Leave</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Max, new { @Class = "form-control", placeholder = ViewBag.maternity })
                            <span class="input-group-addon">In Row</span>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID, new { Value = 2 })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Max, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Annual" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>

                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem here is that when the form submitted with wrong value, the modelstate validated and return error message for ALL of the form like in this picture.
[image]
I want that the error message is only shown for the form i submit, is that possible? Thanks for your help guys

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can only submit one form at a time. You creating invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes and because your `name` attributes are duplicated, client side validation will not work correctly

Comment: Yeah sorry i really new at this, what i want to get is a page for update database like in the picture. And yes i know i can only submit one at a time, i make 4 form to let user decide which they want to update (?)

Comment: You view does not make sense (and its a confusing user experience). You would be better off having a page with 4 links that take you to the appropriate page to edit the specific form (or load the specific form into the page using ajax. If you did want t do this, then you would need 4 separate view models.

Comment: I think will go with one page contain 4 form, maybe i can use tabs so its not confusing for user. The thing with tab is how to set active tab on page load (the tab i press submit)

Comment: Why would you want to degrade performance by generating all that extra html when only 1/4 is needed. Just have buttons that the user can load the appropriate form into the page using ajax (and each form needs to be based on a separate view model)

Comment: Ehm.. The problem is i never use and dont quite understand AJAX, can u give a link that have good tutorial of ajax that suits my case? thankyouu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114312/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-fimblutterr).